# Vba if function in formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use if function in vba with loop, so a i have a code like below

```
Worksheets("Teszt_dec").Cells(i, j + oszlop_number + 5).Formula = "=IIf(Teszt!" & Worksheets("Teszt_dec").Cells(i, j + oszlop_number + 5).address(False, False) & "<$F22,1,0)"
```

and i got these message:

[image]

(that means  #name error just in hungarian)

And if i select the cells, and press enter the error message suddenly disappear and works fine....

So anyone have any idea how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Worksheets("Teszt_dec").Cells(i, j + oszlop_number + 5).Formula = "=Ha(Teszt!" & Worksheets("Teszt_dec").Cells(i, j + oszlop_number + 5).address(False, False) & "<$F22,1,0)"

sorry, this is the whole code

Comment: Is it `Ha`of `IIf` in your formula? Your comment is different from the code you posted, please edit your post. `IIf` is a vba function, `IF` is the English Excel version, and `Ha` seems to be the Hungarian (?) Excel version. You shouldn't use the vba version, and if you want to use the translated hungarian version you should use `.FormulaLocal = ...` instead of `.Formula = ...`, but I suggest using the english version.

Comment: To do correction first record the macro, input formula manually and check how Excel recorded it and incorporate results as per your requirement. It will increase your understanding.

Comment: .FormulaLocal is working! 

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iif` is a VBA function. In your case, you are in need of an Excel formula, because you are calling like this:

`Worksheets("Teszt_dec").Cells(i, j + oszlop_number + 5).Formula`

The Excel formula is `=IF`.

Thus try with `Cells(1,1).Formula = "=IF(condition,true,false)"`